# Proving limits of complex numbers

Tags: limits

Prove $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{z\mathop\to 0}\frac{\overline z^2}{z^2}=1$ and $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{z\mathop\to 0}\frac{\overline z^2}{z}=0 $

Comment: Write $z = r e^{i\theta}$.  But I don't see how the first identity can be true unless you specify how $z \to 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is not correct. For example, let $z_n=\dfrac{1}{n}(1+i)$. Then $\dfrac{\bar{z_n}^2}{z_n^2}=-1$ for all $n$.

For the second, go to polar form, letting $z=re^{i t}$. Then our ratio is $re^{-3it}$, which has limit $0$ as $r\to 0$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+z+to+0+z*^2%2Fz^2 Wolfram Alpha says it is though ?

Comment: Interesting. I am barely acquainted with Wolfram Alpha. It seems highly useful. Somewhat imperfect.

Comment: So does the limit not exist for the first* one?

Comment: @LuciusTarquiniusSuperbus Be wary of using Wolfram Alpha for complex limits.  I have seen quite a few examples of it giving wrong answers when the limit is dependent on the path (hence does not exist).  For instance, look at [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+z+to+infinity+e^z).

Comment: +1 $i^{1/2}$ was the example that came to mind when I saw the question.

Comment: @LuciusTarquiniusSuperbus: the first limit does not exist.